# Chart js Как передать данные для построения графиков с помощью выпадающего списка

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

Передаю данные для построения графиков при помощи кнопок, как переделать код для передачи их при помощи выпадающего списка? То есть кнопки заменить на "дропдаун".

Пример https://plnkr.co/edit/cR0VCbeenPa1YwanWqni?p=preview

**html**

```
<canvas id="myChart" height="100"></canvas>

      <button id="firstData">Add first data</button>
      <button id="secondData">Add second data</button>

<select id=" ">
  <option value=" ">Add first data</option>
  <option value=" ">Add second data</option>
  <option value=" ">etc</option>
</select>
```

**scripts**

```
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "Compras",
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        borderWidth: 2,
        data: [15, 120, 25, 48, 120, 77, 5],
        fill: false
    }],
    options: {
    legend: {
        display: true
    }
    }
};

var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "line",
    data: data,
});

$('button#firstData').click(function() {
    var firstData = {
        label: "Compras",
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        borderWidth: 2,
        data: [15, 120, 25, 48, 120, 77, 5],
        fill: false
};

    data.datasets.push(firstData);
  myBarChart.update();

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если имеется ввиду обрабатывать событие изменения выпадающего списка, можно обработать событие onchange

**html**

```
  <select id="dropdown">
    <option value="first">Add first data</option>
    <option value="second">Add second data</option>
    <option value="etc">etc</option>
  </select>
```

**js**

```
$('#dropdown').change(function(){
const val = $(this).val();
switch (val){
case 'first':
        var firstData = {
        label: "Compras",
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        borderWidth: 2,
        data: [15, 120, 25, 48, 120, 77, 5],
        fill: false
};

    data.datasets.push(firstData);
  myBarChart.update();
  break;
  case 'second':
            var newDataset = {
        label: "Vendas",
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(99, 255, 132, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(99, 255, 132, 1)',
        borderWidth: 2,
        data: [10, 20, 60, 40, 50, 60, 70],
        fill: false
    }

  data.datasets.push(newDataset);
    myBarChart.update();
  break;
}
});
```

Пример: https://plnkr.co/edit/zjwan468hEgVmmyHiZKu?p=preview